# Ubuntu 20.04 / 21.04 stuck in grub after encryption

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, encryption, initrd

### SOLUTION:

The problem originates from large initrd.img files (~100MB) generated with MODULES=most that can't be loaded due to size limitations. This can be solved by switching to MODULES=dep which generates initrd.img files of approximately 55MB.

### Problem:

I've tried to perform a fresh install of Ubuntu Budgie on a clean drive with UEFI boot mode and GPT partition table but every time, no matter the settings, I manage to enter my passphrase, select "Ubuntu" in the grub menu but then the screen remains grey as if it's stuck in grub.

I've followed these guides with both 20.04 and 21.04 Ubuntu Budgie versions (https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads/) :

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019
- https://mutschler.eu/linux/install-guides/ubuntu-btrfs/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/VeraCrypt/comments/n2vk26/installing_linux_root_partition_to_standard/

I've also tried using only the encryption option proposed in the installation menu, and since that doesn't encrypt boot, I go directly to the grub selection screen and get stuck after selecting Ubuntu.

The advanced grub sub-menu shows this:

```
Loading Linux 5.11.0-17-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
_
```

I've also tried booting with the following parameters (one at the time, without the "") but it still gets stuck at "Loading initial ramdisk ...": "nomodeset", "nouveau.modeset=0", "modprobe.blacklist=nouveau".

I then tried the following parameter (all at once):

- removed from the "linux ..." line: `quiet splash`
- added to the "linux ..." line: `earlyprintk=efi,keep debug systemd.log_level=info`
- added below the final "initrd /initrd.img..." line:
  `echo 'Loaded Linux kernel...'` followed below by `sleep 5`

These did not produce any different result, as I was still stuck with "Loading initial ramdisk ..."

Furthermore, the REISUB SysRq hotkey sequence does not produce any results.

To rule some things out, the following did not impact the abnormal behavior:

- Secure boot on or off
- SATA mode set to AHCI, RAID or disabled
- Various Intel settings
- TPM enabled/disabled/cleared

These are some logs I got from the installer:

```
efifb: mode is 3840x2160x32, linelength=15360, pages=1

kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA GM107 (1171b0a2)

kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 022554 [ IBUS ]
...
kernel: [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
...
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Disabling PCI power management to
avoid bug
...
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 619444 [ IBUS ]
```

**Just to be clear, this only happens when any form of encryption is added to "/". Unencrypted installations work perfectly.**

Furthermore, **it has been proven that the installation works** as it booted from a virtual machine installed within the live usb installer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. I am happy that you found the answer to your question. Please don't put the answer inside the question. Press the **answer your own question** button below and write the detailed solution there. Then after the mandatory waiting period accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem originates from large initrd.img files (~100MB) generated with MODULES=most that can't be loaded due to size limitations. This can be solved by switching to MODULES=dep which generates initrd.img files of approximately 55MB.

See this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1931024